# Android difference between using ImageResource and Drawable

Tags: android, android-studio, drawable, android-drawable, android-resources

I am new to Android development and I have originally set my graphics for the user to drag using **SetImageResource**. However later in development it does not have methods I required so I ended up using **SetImageDrawable** later on for dragging images and placing them in new spots.

What are the core differences between these two? I have been looking online and am still uncertain on these key differences and how they will affect my program.

Example of how I set the images originally on the view using **setImageResource**:

```
case 'J':
    if (tempFlip[9]) {
        GameBoardImages[k].setImageResource(temp[9]);
    } else {
        temp[9] = symbolTilesID[k];
        tempFlip[9] = true;
        GameBoardImages[k].setImageResource(symbolTilesID[k]);
    }
    break;
```

Then how I have it set in **OnDragListener** using **setImageDrawable**:

```
target = GameBoardImages[ImageNumber]; //Spot getting dragged to

dragged = (ImageView) myDragEvent.getLocalState(); //Dragging item

target_draw = target.getDrawable();
dragged_draw = dragged.getDrawable();

dragged.setImageDrawable(target_draw);
target.setImageDrawable(dragged_draw);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `setImageResource()` takes in a drawable resource ID (which is an int).

PRO: You are passing in an integer, which is very small in terms of memory. If there are several method calls before your call to `setImageResource()`, they can easily pass around this int with no memory issues.

CON: Because you are passing in an integer, the `setImageResource()` method must perform Bitmap reading and decoding in order to display the image.  The method performs this on the UI thread, which could cause a 'latency hiccup' depending on the size of the image and the processing power of the device.  This would result in your user seeing a lag or funny behavior on the screen as the image is processed.

The method `setImageDrawable()` takes in the actual Drawable object.

PRO: You already have the actual Drawable, so there is no need to process this data in order to display it. For this method you won't see the latency issues on screen.

CON: The drawback here is that you might end up passing a drawable around between other methods in order to have access to it to make the `setImageDrawable()` method call.  Passing around Drawable objects a lot isn't a great idea, as they can be large.

Comment: Thank you for your information this was quite helpful. Any chance you also know why I cannot setDrawable image on a view with no drawable? For some reason it only lets me do this on another drawable. If you don't it is fine I just figured there is no harm in asking. The problem is When I do this I always loose a drawable image on the view.Thanks again!

Comment: @Kio Krofovitch, your answer doesn't make sense memory–wise. Objects are always stored in the heap, and only integer references are passed around the operand stack, so there's no advantage in using resource identifiers in this regard. Also, pictures taken from resources will become drawables as well. Resource identifiers will just make it all slower, since they involve resolving resources. Using them is still a good practice, however, for as far as Android resources are concerned.

Comment: @Kio Krofovitch, moreover, no 'funny behavior' may happen on the screen while decoding and showing the image, not at least on modern devices, which have got GPUs and are hardware–accelerated. Indeed, as soon as the image is fully decoded and stored in RAM (precisely in the heap), it will get copied to the GPU memory and rendered at once in the next presentation. This will happen in some JNI calls used by the Android managed code to reach the unmanaged drivers manufacturers write.